# Wordpress rewrite sensitive URL and files and avoid access to them

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i don't know if it even is possible or i will get problems with the linking of things, but i'm struggling currently with a problem von URL Rewrites for Wordpress wp-admin URL and wp-login.php

My intention is to avoid access to /wp-admin/ and /wp-login.php during i will give the apache the ability to pass thru using another request url.

Hope you could help, and maybe say to me, if this try will work at all.

The response currently is, that if i [F] the Rewrite the new url/file will be blocked, too.

It's a bit wild, trying to many things out.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Die Anweisungen (Zeilen) zwischen `BEGIN WordPress` und `END WordPress` sind
# dynamisch generiert und sollten nur über WordPress-Filter geändert werden.
# Alle Änderungen an den Anweisungen zwischen diesen Markierungen werden überschrieben.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/

    # BEGIN
    # Options +FollowSymLinks

    # works %{REDIRECT_IS_BACKEND}
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^(.*?)/?backend/?(.*)$#">
        SetEnv IS_BACKEND "1"
    </If>

    #works %{REDIRECT_IS_LOGIN}
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^(.*?)/login(.*)$#">
       SetEnv IS_LOGIN "1"
    </If>

     RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_LOGIN} !^1$
     RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^.*?/wp-login.php$
     RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

     #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/backend/?(.*)
     #RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?backend/?(.*)$ $1wp-admin$2 [NC,L,PT,E=IS_BACKEND:1]

     #RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_BACKEND} 1
     #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*?/wp-admin/?.*$
     #RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

     # works
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/login\??(.*)$
     RewriteRule ^(.*?/?)login(\??.*)$ $1wp-login.php$2 [NC,L,PT,E=IS_LOGIN:1]

     # END

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

UPDATE ------------------------------
So, I've found a working solution:

```
# BEGIN

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*?/?backend/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*?/?)backend(/?.*)$ $1wp-admin$2 [L,E=IS_BACKEND:1,END]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_IS_BACKEND} !^1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*?/?wp-admin/?.*$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*?/login\??.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*?/?)login(\??.*)$ $1wp-login.php$2 [L,E=IS_LOGIN:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_IS_LOGIN} !^1$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^.*?/wp-login.php$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

# END
```

But now i'm stucking on Cookie Path - as it is defined and there seems to be no hooks, maybe i try to edit the config.php

Answer (score 0):

After some time of testing and fiddling with the rewrite i've found a solution that seems to work properly:

```
# BEGIN of our changes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*?/?backend/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*?/?)backend(/?.*)$ $1wp-admin$2 [L,E=IS_BACKEND:1,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wordpress/wp-admin/load-styles.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php$
RewriteRule ^.* - [L,E=IS_BACKEND:1,END]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_IS_BACKEND} !^1$    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*?/?wp-admin/?.*$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*?/login\??.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*?/?)login(\??.*)$ $1wp-login.php$2 [L,E=IS_LOGIN:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_IS_LOGIN} !^1$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^.*?/wp-login.php$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
# END of our changes
```

For a full description on integrate it into Wordpress:
(German): https://www.sumedia-howto.de/wordpress/wordpress-urls-rewrite-zum-schutz-sensibler-dateien-und-pfade/